# Can Mockito handle methods that return generics in Scala?

Tags: generics, scala, mockito

I want to mock the return from [javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, getParameterNames()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterNames%28%29). Therefore:

```scala
import org.specs.Specification
import org.specs.mock.Mockito
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest

object SomethingSpec extends Specification with Mockito {
    "Something" should {
        "do something" in {
            val request = mock[HttpServletRequest]

            // This is fine
            val elements: java.util.Enumeration[String] = List("p1", "p2").iterator

            // But this bombs
            request.getParameterNames() return elements
        }
    }
}
```

Compilation of the last line results in this difficult-to-understand error:

```
found   : java.util.Enumeration[String]
required: java.util.Enumeration[?0] where type ?0
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried to cast the return value from the HttpServletRequest like

```
request.getParameterNames().asInstanceOf[java.util.Enumeration[String]] returns elements
```

It seems, getParameterNames returns an untyped Enumeration.

Comment: Seems like a Mockito bug, since getParameterNames definitely returns an Enumeration[String]. But this helps me work around the problem. Thanks!